# Reload Form on reload/refresh of subgrid in Dynamics 365 CRM Unified Interface

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-uci

I have a scenario where in **Orders Form** there is a **Invoice Schedule Sub-grid**. I need to Refresh/Reload the **Main Form** when the **Invoice Schedule Sub-grid** is reloaded on ***Deactivating*** a particular record in the Sub-grid.

**P.S:** This scenario is for Dynamics 365 CRM Unified Interface (UCI). I have tried all the three Sub-grid events but does not help in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach a custom event handler to deal this. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2019/12/06/subgrid-refresh-events/)

```
var globalFormContext;

function myFormOnload(executionContext) {
  globalFormContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 

  addSubgridEventListener();
} 

function addSubgridEventListener(){
  var gridContext = globalFormContext.getControl("<your_subgrid_name>");
  //ensure that the subgrid is ready…if not wait and call this function again
  if (gridContext == null){
     setTimeout(function () { addSubgridEventListener(); }, 500);
     return;
  }
  //bind the event listener when the subgrid is ready
  gridContext.addOnLoad(subgridEventListener);

}

function subgridEventListener(context){
  globalFormContext.data.refresh(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi @arunvinoth, Thanks for the answer, It worked but I was getting a bug which was putting the Sub-grid into infinite loop. As my basic requirement was to refresh the Main Form Ribbon I used `globalFormContext.ui.refreshRibbon(false);` instead of `globalFormContext.data.refresh(false);` which is working fine for me.

Comment: Does this work? I tested with this code but the only time the method "subgridEventListener" gets called is when the form loads. If I add or delete records from the subgrid nothing happens.. Unified Interface. 2019 release wave 2 enabled
Server version: 9.1.0000.16843
Client version: 1.4.583-2004.2

Comment: @TobyFieldgroove start a new question and tag this thread if it adds more context

Comment: I have an issue with this solution, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814065/problem-with-reload-form-on-reload-refresh-of-subgrid-in-dynamics-365-crm-unifie

Answer (score 0):

This latest code verified and works in v9 unified interface
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/grids/gridcontrol/addonload

Code snippet:

```
//On load of main form event
function OnloadOfMainForm(executionContext) {
// call onLoad of subgrid function
  SubgridEventHandler(executionContext);
} 

var globalFormContext;
function SubgridEventHandler(executionContext){
//make formContext as global
  globalFormContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 
  var gridContext = globalFormContext.getControl("subgrid_name");

  //Verify the subgrid is loaded, if not recursively call function again
  if (gridContext != null && gridContext != undefined){
      //don't try to pass formEontext some time it doesn't works
      gridContext.addOnLoad(SubgridFunctionExe);
     }else{
        setTimeout(function () { SubgridEventHandler(); }, 200);
     }
}

//It triggers onLoad of form, on load and on refresh of subgrid
//as well on add new record and on delete of record it will trigger
function SubgridFunctionExe(){
// here use globalFormContext
  globalFormContext.data.refresh(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For UCI:
From ribbon button pass the parameter of PrimaryControl and use below code to Refresh.

```
PrimaryControl.refresh();
```