# Problem with Reload Form on reload/refresh of subgrid in Dynamics 365 CRM Unified Interface

Tags: refresh, reload, dynamics-365, subgrid

I have the exact same scenario as this thread:
[Reload Form on reload/refresh of subgrid in Dynamics 365 CRM Unified Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929848/reload-form-on-reload-refresh-of-subgrid-in-dynamics-365-crm-unified-interface)

The suggested solution does not work for me unfortunately. The only time the method "subgridEventListener" gets called is when the form loads. If I add or delete records from the subgrid nothing happens..

Does anyone have a possible solution to this problem?

Unified Interface. 2019 release wave 2 enabled Server version: 9.1.0000.16843 Client version: 1.4.583-2004.2 –

Comment: Did you debug? So the eventhandler is attached to event but not triggering on subgrid reload event? Can you add your snippet you’re using?

Answer (score 0):

```
//On load of main form event
function OnloadOfMainForm(executionContext) {
// call onLoad of subgrid function
  SubgridEventHandler(executionContext);
} 

var globalFormContext;
function SubgridEventHandler(executionContext){
//make formContext as global
  globalFormContext = executionContext.getFormContext(); 
  var gridContext = globalFormContext.getControl("subgrid_name");

  //Verify the subgrid is loaded, if not recursively call function again
  if (gridContext != null && gridContext != undefined){
      //don't try to pass formEontext some time it doesn't works
      gridContext.addOnLoad(SubgridFunctionExe);
     }else{
        setTimeout(function () { SubgridEventHandler(); }, 200);
     }
}

//Perform operation onLoad of form and subgrid, on refresh of subgrid it will trigger
//as well on add new record and on delete of record it will trigger
function SubgridFunctionExe(){
// here use globalFormContext
  globalFormContext.data.refresh(false);
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/grids/gridcontrol/addonload

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.